# In the MinCostFlow solver, how can I predict beforehand if the maximum cost magnitude is too high?

Tags: or-tools

I am using the Google OR-tools library (v6.4) in a program (specifically, the MinCostFlow class in the library). For my requirement, my cost matrix consists of floating-point values. However, since an instance of this class can only accept arcs with integer costs, I am multiplying each cost with a scaling factor of a power of 10 (10<sup>16</sup>, at the moment) and then passing that as the cost for an arc.

The problem is that when the number of nodes are high (eg: 10000 sources and 10000 sinks), I am getting the following error at runtime:

```
E0612 12:08:45.378520 231034880 min_cost_flow.cc:237] Maximum cost magnitude 9999999857054488 is too high for the number of nodes. Try changing the data.
```

How can I predict whether a particular cost value is too high given the number of nodes, before running the algorithm? This would allow me to select a scaling factor appropriately, in order to prevent failure at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CostValue` is defined as `typedef int64 CostValue`
src: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/9487eb85f4620f93abfed64899371be88d65c6ec/ortools/graph/ebert_graph.h#L204

The code computing this check is:

```
CostValue max_cost_magnitude = 0;
// Traverse the initial arcs of the graph:
for (ArcIndex arc = 0; arc < graph_->num_arcs(); ++arc) {
  const CostValue cost_magnitude = MathUtil::Abs(scaled_arc_unit_cost_[arc]);
  max_cost_magnitude = std::max(max_cost_magnitude, cost_magnitude);
  ...
}
...
if (log(std::numeric_limits<CostValue>::max()) <
  log(max_cost_magnitude + 1) + log(graph_->num_nodes() + 1)) {
 LOG(FATAL)...;
}
```

src: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/9487eb85f4620f93abfed64899371be88d65c6ec/ortools/graph/min_cost_flow.cc#L235

Comment: I apologize for commenting so late on this post, I ran into an issue while implementing the solution. Despite applying a similar pre-emptive check in my Java client, I am getting the status returned from the solve() method as `BAD_COST_RANGE` (in rare cases). This is the check I applied:

`(Math.log(maxCost + 1) + Math.log(numberOfNodes + 1) > Math.log(Long.MAX_VALUE))`

Comment: Here, maxCost is the maximum cost value for an arc that I'm passing through the client. If this check returns true, then I scale down all the cost values and try again, till the check fails. There are some cases where this check is returning false at the client, but then goes on and returns BAD_COST_RANGE from the library code.

Comment: Going through the min_cost_flow.cc file, in the checkCostRange() method, the values in `scaled_arc_unit_cost_` seem to be arc costs before they are multiplied with the number of nodes in the graph. So, my client check seems to be indentical to the one in the c++ code. Do you see any reason why both the checks would return different results?